# MVVM Light - RaisePropertyChanged not working

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone, mvvm-light

I have a ViewModel that is bound to one page called SettingsView. 
In this page i have some properties like so:

```
public string SettingsHeaderTitle { get { return AppResources.settings_header_title; } }
```

I have one button that navigates to another page where we can change language and then goes back to SettingsPage.
I had implemented a command like so:

```
public void UpdateView() 
{
    RaisePropertyChanged(string.Empty);
}
```

My problem is that when I call this command from on Loadedd or NavigatedTo events nothing happens. Then I added a button to call this command (for debug purposes) and the Page is updated successfully.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem is your data in view aren't pass to ViewModel, realluy? Then, 
Review if: The class properties have PropertyChanged implemented. 
Also you bind is correct, your mode = two-way and UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your ViewModels like so

```
public class SelectionItem<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private AppliesTo _appliesTo;
    public AppliesTo AppliesTo
    {
        get { return _appliesTo; }
        set
        {
            _appliesTo = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("AppliesTo"));
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I just noticed you're using MVVM Light, then it becomes even easier, in your ViewModels inherit from `ViewModelBase` and make your property like this:

```
private bool _isComparisonRun;
public bool IsComparisonRun
{
    get { return _isComparisonRun; }
    set
    {
        if (_isComparisonRun == value) return;
        _isComparisonRun = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsComparisonRun);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually my ViewModel implements ViewModelBase, and I Want to update all properties from the ViewModel at once, because the language has changed.